# UITabBar items cover only half of the screen when clicked in landscape mode

Tags: ios6, screen-orientation

In my main view ,there are 4 tab bar items which are always present at the bottom of my screen. Now when I rotate my device to landscape mode and click any of the tabs, then that tab bar view covers only half of the screen. I tried, but did not succeed. I am posting the screen shot of the view:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Are you setting the frame for the selected view after tapping the control or while rotating?

Comment: i have created table view through xib. when i rotate from portrait to landscape, the frame is resized but when i click other tabs it displays as i have shown above ie half of the screen.